# How do I use react to show different <div> based on the data imported?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a personal project and am trying to get my website to show different things based on the tab they have selected.  I am trying to figure out how to only show my className="container" when there is an image and to have the className"skillsList" only show formatted text with a background color.  As of right now it shows both on each tab.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import PortfolioList from "../portfolioList/PortfolioList";
import { skillsPortfolio,
        webPortfolio,
        mobilePortfolio,
        designPortfolio,
        contentPortfolio} from "../../data";

export default function Portfolio() {
        const [selected, setSelected] = useState("skills");
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const list = [
            {
                id: "skills",
                title: "Skills",
            },
            {
                id: "python",
                title: "Python",
            },
            {
                id: "sql",
                title: "SQL",
            },
            {
                id: "dataanalysis",
                title: "Data Analysis",
            },
        ];

        useEffect(()=>{

            switch(selected){
                case "skills":
                    setData(skillsPortfolio);
                    break;
                case "python":
                    setData(webPortfolio);
                    break;
                case "sql":
                    setData(mobilePortfolio);
                    break;
                case "dataanalysis":
                    setData(designPortfolio);
                    break;
                case "content":
                    setData(contentPortfolio);
                    break;
                default:
                    setData(skillsPortfolio);

            }

        }, [selected])

    return(
        <div className="portfolio" id="portfolio">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <ul>
                {list.map((item) => (
                    <PortfolioList title={item.title}
                                   active={selected=== item.id}
                                   setSelected={setSelected}
                                   id={item.id}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>

            
            <div className="container">
                {data.map((d)=> (
                <div className="item">
                    <img src={d.img}/>
                    <h3>{d.title}</h3>
                </div>
                    ))}
            </div>
            <div className="skillsList">
                {data.map((d)=> (
                <p>{d.skill}</p>
                ))}
            </div>

        </div>
    )

}
```

The data I'm mapping has img for some entries and skill for others.

[Skills tab with no "img" in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7P9A.png)

[Python tab with no "skill" in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD0Bi.png)

I don't know how to conditionally display or hide components based on info in the data.  I only want to show "container" sometimes and "skillsList" sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both blocks with a conditional that checks whether the length of `data` is greater than zero.

```
  {data.length > 0 && (
    <div className="container">
      {data.map((d) => (
        <div className="item">
          <img src={d.img} />
          <h3>{d.title}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}

  {data.length > 0 && (
    <div className="skillsList">
      {data.map((d) => (
        <p>{d.skill}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
```

This is with the assumption that data will always be an array. If it isn't and may be null or undefined at some times, you can add the following to the conditional.

```
{data && data.length > 0 && (
    ...rest of code
)}
```

Comment: This answer is valid, however you could simplify the code by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)  (if `data` may be `null` or `undefined` at any point): `data?.map(d => ( ... ) )`

Comment: Yeah, because he because he needed the two divs hidden when the conditions weren't met, I did the condition around the parent div, not just the data